# Как изменить фон у QWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

Здравствуйте, у меня есть такой код:

```
void detail::setBackground(QWidget *widget, const QColor &color){
    const QPalette palet(QPalette::Background, color);
    widget->setPalette(palet);
    widget->setAutoFillBackground(true);
}
```

По идее он должен менять задний фон виджета, но по-факту фон устанавливается только 1 раз, а потом изменяется только только ободок шириной внесколько пикселей.

Так вот как сделать так, чтобы фон изменялся полностью?

Answer (score 1):

Решение проблемы в строке

```
const QPalette palet(QPalette::Background, color);
```

нужно

```
const QPalette palet(color);
```

Во втором случае изменяется цвет именно кнопки.